# what is the difference between right and left join in oracle ? if we can achieve what left join can do in a right join why use 2 separate join?

Tags: mysql, oracle, plsql

We have 2 tables Sales & product with some columns.

I do a left join

1. select X,X,X from sales left join product on XXX;
   (this gives a left join result)
2. select X,X,X from product left join sales on XXX;
   (this would give me a right join result of query 1 agreed ? then y have left and right join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they were the same, probably there'd be only one.

Visual representation of SQL joins, to make it clearer to you:

[image]